# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function (In new version)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

There is similar questions in stackoverflow but none of that fixed my issues... Maybe because that questions are old and the solutions for older versions....   So I tried different methods I saw but none of it helped still showing the same error.. please help me fix it friends...

Create.js file:

```
    import { FirebaseContext, AuthContext } from '../../store/Context';    
    const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        firebase.storage().ref(`/image/${image.name}`).put(image).on('state_changed').then(({ ref }) => {
          ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
          })
        })
      }
      return (
    <Fragment>
    <button className="uploadBtn" onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload and Submit</button>
    <Fragment/>
    )
```

I have added only the necessary parts here.
The firebase config file has the following imports:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage'
```

I am doing my project in React.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the `compat` paths of `auth` and `firestore`, which means you can use the namespaced syntax when using those products. But for `storage` you're importing the default path, meaning you must use the new modular syntax of the SDK version you use.

To be able to use the namespaced syntax for storage too:

```
import 'firebase/compat/storage'
```

Comment: I have figured out a solution... i don't know weather its a proper way or not. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you figured out a different solution, can you post that as an answer so others can benefit?

Answer (score 0):

For Uploading image to firebase storage  and get the url for the uploaded image, You can use this:

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes,getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const Create = () => {

 const handleSubmit = () => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/image/${image.name}`);
    //uploads the file to firebase storage
    uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    }
    ).then(() => {
      //gets the url for the uploaded image
      getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `/image/${image.name}`)).then((url) => {
        console.log('url is: ' + url);
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <button className="uploadBtn" onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
       </div>
    </Fragment>
)
}
```